# Is there a way to know if a HttpResponse is in Https?

Tags: c#, .net, https

In a method, I need to know if the response is in Http or Https in order to redirect the response or to make a BinaryWrite but I only have a HttpResponse in parameter.

Anyone know if it's possible to use the HttpResponse to know that?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I want to know if it's possible to know if a HttpResponse is HTTP or HTTPS, because I prefer not to use HttpContext.Current.Request if possible.

Comment: If you're using IIS 7+, why not take care of the http -> https redirect with the rewrite functionality instead... that'll keep your code nice and blissfully unaware of that detail.

Comment: Are you running ASP.Net server-side code?

Comment: Try rephrasing your question - hard to tell what is it about...

Comment: @jonnyGold I can't because the behavior of the method is defined by HTTPS and the website has to deal with either HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: @SLaks Yes, but I don't think that change the possibility of the HttpResponse class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. You can find out from the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx), but a response is just a stream of data returned in relation to the Request.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you need;

```
System.Uri currentUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

if (!currentUrl.Scheme.Equals(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, stringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
  //Do something here
}
```

It is not possible to extract this information from the HttpResponse object as this is what will be sent *back* to the client, over the same communication protocol that the request was probably requested from. You will need to use the Request object to check for an SSL connection.

Comment: There is HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection but I prefer not to use HttpContext.Current.Request if possible.

Comment: What is the reason for avoiding `HttpContext.Current.Request`?

Comment: Just avoiding to modify a lots of code. It's a bad reason, I know. But you made me think that I haven't try to use directly HttpContext.Current.Request in my method.

Answer (score 1):

HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection property will do the job look at the example on the MS link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection(v=vs.110).aspx